# Download the YouTube video file directly to user's computer through browser

Tags: php, youtube, tcp

```
<?php
$youtubeUrl =  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko2JcxecV2E"; 
$content = json_encode ($file = shell_exec("youtube-dl.exe $youtubeUrl "));
$input_string =$content;
$regex_pattern = "/Destination:(.*.mp4)/";
$boolean = preg_match($regex_pattern, $input_string, $matches_out);
$extracted_string=$matches_out[0];

$file =explode(': ',$extracted_string,2)[1];      

// Quick check to verify that the file exists
if( !file_exists($file) ) die("File not found");
// Force the download
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"" );
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;");
readfile($file);

?>
```

When I run this file the respective YouTube video is first downloaded to the localhost server folder where this PHP file is, using `youtube-dl.exe` and then it is pushed from that folder to browser download (forced download).

How to directly start the download to user's browser?

Also the file is running fine on localhost but not on remote server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to use a version of youtube-dl for a platform of your webserver. The `youtube-dl.exe` is a build for Windows, while most webhostings use Linux.

Then use the [`passthru`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) PHP function to run the `youtube-dl` with the [`-o -` command-line parameter](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#output-template). The parameters makes `youtube-dl` output the downloaded video to its standard output, while the `passthru` passes the standard output to a browser.

You also need to output the headers before the the `passthru`. Note that you cannot know the download size in this case.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"...\"" );
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

passthru("youtube-dl -o - $youtubeUrl");
```

If you need a video metadata (like a filename), you can run the `youtube-dl` first with the `-j` command-line parameter to get the JSON data without downloading the video.

Also you need 1) Python interpreter on the web server 2) to be able to use the `passthru` function 3) connectivity to YouTube from the PHP scripts. All these are commonly restricted on webhostings.

Comment: That's a bit out of the scope of this question, but the docs seem pretty comprehensive depending on what you want to do: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is probably within: `shell_exec("youtube-dl.exe $youtubeUrl ")`

Firstly, some hosts disable shell_exec for security reasons.

Secondly, youtube-dl.exe looks like it is probably a windows script, where as your remote server is probably Linux based.