# YouTube-dl server direct file download

Tags: php, python, download, youtube, youtube-dl

I have succesfully installed youtube-dl on my server and from command line everything is working like a charm.

Now I want to be able to call a link on my site from my web browser which directly initiates a download of the file. So in that order:

1. Open site in browser (for example http://example.com/download.php?v=as43asx3
2. YouTube-dl processes the input
3. Web-browser downloads file
4. Temporary files will be deleted from server

I am not very experienced with this, but nevertheless need to solve this issue.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as "too broad". You are expected to show some [research effort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way of doing this and I would appreciate seeing it, however, here is how I solved it:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);

//getting ID from URL
$youtubeID = $_GET['videoID'] ;

//getting audio file from youtube video via youtube-dl
exec('~/bin/youtube-dl --verbose --extract-audio -o "~/html/YouTubeDownloader/%(id)s.%(ext)s" '.$youtubeID);

//downloading file to client/browser
$filename = $youtubeID.".m4a";
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-type: audio/m4a");
readfile($filename);

//deleting file again
unlink($filename);?>
```

Comment: Can't we make it directly downloadable to client instead of first download to server and then from server to client.? 
I tried this but didn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074295/download-the-youtube-video-file-directly-to-users-computer-through-browser/29075181#29075181